# Merging an existing branch from one repository to another branch of a new repository

Tags: git, github

I created a new repository in the company's github account and I added myself as a contributor to the repository. I wanted to move everything from user A's repository (usera.git) to the newly created company's repository (company.git). I had a clone of user A's repository on my machine, as I am a contributor to it. I also have staged commits on a branch of usera.git lets call brancha. I want to move the whole history of brancha, plus my staged commits, to the company.git repository's master branch.

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (push)

git remote add company https://github.com/company/company.git

git remote -v
company https://github.com/company/company.git (fetch)
company https://github.com/company/company.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (push)

git status
# On branch usera
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
#       ...
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. The newly created company.git is an empty repository at this moment. I want to move the whole history, plus changes to be committed (I don't want to commit the changes to usera's repository), to the new company.git repository's master branch. When I run

```
git fetch company
```

Nothing happens (usually you would see some feedback like [new branch]). I run "git branch" and no new master branch was added from company repository.

I expect for it to pull down the master branch, and then allow me to checkout that master branch, and then merge the whole history and staged changes into it.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `git push company usera:master` ? That is, push to the `company` remote your local `usera` branch and call it `master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no remote master to pull down and merge with; as you said, the `company` repo is empty.

But that also means that any such thing is unnecessary. You can do `git push company usera:master` to push the local branch `usera` to `master` on `company`. You could add the `-u` option to that push to make `usera` always track `company/master`, or you could use `git checkout` afterwards to create a new branch tracking `company/master`.

Comment: One thing I noticed this does is when I run "git remote show company", it says that my local master branch is out of date. Is that local master branch still pointing to usera repository or the company repository?

Comment: I run "git checkout -b company company/master". And then " git remote show company". Strangely it says this: Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    company merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date). What does this mean? I cannot push to company using the company branch?